# When uploading multiple small files it takes up to 60 seconds for it to complete

Tags: node.js, file-upload, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to setup uploading to google cloud storage, and typically I will have about 200 concurrent uploads of files that are in size of 5 to 10kb. When I'm using the same code with local ceph s3 compatible storage, upload time is barely more than 2-3ms (which is obvious), and when uploading to google s3-like storage, if I have 3 to 5 threads upload time is usually within 200ms for a file. However, as soon as I reach decent concurrency - I get linear increments on the upload times.

First 10 files are uploaded within 200ms, next 10 within 5s, next 10 within 10s and so on till it get to a 60s.
If I use multiple processes - the result is the same. I'm using nodejs to perform the uploads with https://github.com/Automattic/knox module, pool is turned off, so its not an issue of sockets being queued up. I've tested enabling pool with maxSockets set to 500 or so, doesnt help much. When checking with sockstat, concurrently I only have up to 40 connections opened to google servers, even though I would initiate more than 500 to 1000 uploads at the same time using 16 processes. This is extremely weird.

Can anybody help me to diagnose the problem? Is there a limit of connections that google would allow to be opened from a single ip address?

I'm sure it's not a problem with my code, because beforehand I was using it with a local s3 storage (by local I mean I have a cluster of 20 machines with disks, and even though it's in the same data center if there would've been a problem with blocking operations or lack of sockets or anything similar I would've seen an increase in the upload time just as well, but there is not such a thing when using ceph). Reason I'm trying to migrate to google is that managing dying hard drives is pretty annoying and that happens often

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google's quotas page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Sockets),

> Sockets
>
> Daily Data and Per-Minute (Burst) Data Limits
> Applications using sockets are rate limited on a per minute and a per day basis. Per minute limits are set to handle burst behavior from applications.

The page also shows the limits. You might be running into them, or it could be a limitation of the hardware Google has your app running on.

Comment: I don't think its likely that the app hits socket limits, because I've tested this with only a single process, as well as socket pool, where I would have sockets pre-opened and it didn't make the difference, overall picture is the same

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its disk throughput problem, check your server iostat first. May be your disk it is too slow too handle file traffic or you got stuck because of open socket limits or file descriptor limits.
If this is the case some problems can be fixed via OS fine tuning. If its your disk latency problem then you can switch from hdd to ssd or increase your cluster size.